# Xcode - Add a target app to main app

Tags: xcode, project, target, macos-sierra

I have an application in Xcode which I can compile.
When I do a Product -> Archive I am getting a macOS App Archive which I can export and publish.

Now I created a 2nd target in my project which is also an .app and which I want to be added to the 1st .app.
So I added a "Copy Files" Build Phase to my 1st target, set the destination to "Resources" and added my 2nd target to the list.

When I now do a Product -> Archive I'm getting a Generic Xcode Archive which I cannot export as an .app.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks